# JavaScript Passing Element but Receiving Window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to pass "this" from:

```
myVar = setInterval("displayDate(this )",1000);
```

and is passing "div.test" like it should when I step through it, but when receiving it in:

```
function displayDate(obj){
}
```

It says that it is "Window"???  Below is the JavaScript I am building.  I am trying to build a foundation for classes that trigger events and eventually I am going to be changing the elements.src=".jpg" by a variable rate (now set to 100) through Sprite parsing.  But I am currently stuck on this and I don't want to have to insert onmousemove attributes, etc. in the .html code to keep it clean. . . keep in mind this is only my third day writing .html/.css/.js so any help is appreciated!

```
// This helps create a static variable that isn't polluting the global namespace
var incr = (function () {
    var i = 0;
    return function(){ return i++; };
})();

// This perform all of the functions that we would like with some error handling
function displayDate(obj){

    var counter = incr();

    try{
        obj.innerHTML=counter;
    }catch(err){
        var txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n";
        txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
        txt+="Click OK to continue.\n\n";
        alert(txt);
    }
}

// This is our trigger that sets an interval for our main Java function
$(function(){
    var myVar;
    $(".test").hover( function() {
        // The mouse has entered the element, can reference the element via 'this'
        myVar = setInterval("displayDate(this )",100);
    },function () {
        // The mouse has left the element, can reference the element via 'this'
        clearInterval(myVar);
    }
    );
});
```

Comment: Why do you have "displayDate(this)" in quotes?

Comment: you shouldn't pass strings to setTimeout or setInterval

Comment: Watson yea you were right, I gave you the plus 1! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time the `displayDate` function is called, your into another scope and `this` is your window object (not the div element anymore). To resolve, you can do like this:

```
$(".test").hover( function() {
    var self = this;

    myVar = setInterval(function() {
        displayDate(self);
    },1000);
}, function() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
});
```

Comment: I would say this is 100% correct, removing the quotes triggered the event but then it was lost after the first one which makes sense after Mike's comment.  Thanks everyone, wow what a great community!

Answer (score 0):

instead of setInterval("displayDate(this )",100);

```
$(".test").hover( function() {
var that = $(this);
setInterval(function () {
displayDate(that);

},100);
```

Comment: since you are passing a jquery object try obj.html(counter);

Comment: it seemed to be the $ causing issues, other than that it is the same as Mike's answer which works, thanks!